# Add variable to a URL (node, express)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using node and express. What I want to do is to do is make a mix of `res.render` and `res.redirect`.

Thing is, `res.render` can only receive a `.ejs` file and data, and redirect will go to a specific URL. What I need to do is go to a specific URL (e.g. `/reviews/new/:id`), render a `.ejs` file and give some data to it.

This is my code. I can't use session or cookies for this project.

This are the routes, user enters to edit a review of some show. If it is a new review, the id of the show is in the URL, if the user is editing one, the ID of the review is on the URL. Either way, if something fails, I have to append something to this URL and send data.

```
router.get('/new/:id', controller.newReview);

router.post('/store', controller.checkBeforeStoringReview);

router.get('/edit/:id', controller.editReview);

router.post('/update', controller.checkBeforeUpdatingReview);
```

This is the function to check auth before updating.

```js
checkBeforeUpdatingReview: function(req, res) { // auth before updating review (can't use session or cookies)
        console.log(req.body)
        DB
            .User
            .findOne(
                {
                    where : {
                        email: req.body.email,
                    },

                }
            )
            .then (function (results) {
                if (results[0] != '') {
                    if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, results.password)) {
                        return module.exports.updateReview(req, res, results)
                    } else { // same as catch
                        return res.render('reviews/edit/', { // i'm missing the ID (which i have in req.params.id) at the end of the route
                            id : req.params.id,
                            errors : "Incorrect username or password", 
                            email : req.body.email,
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch (function (error) {
                console.log(error)
                return res.render('reviews/edit/', { // i'm missing the ID (which i have in req.params.id) at the end of the route
                    id : req.params.id,
                    errors : "An unexpected error happened", 
                    email : req.body.email,
                });
            })
    },
```

If everything's ok, as seen above, it goes directly to this function

```
updateReview: function(req, res, results) { // update review
        console.log(req.body)
        DB
            .Review
            .update(req.body,
                {
                    where : {
                        id: req.body.review_id,
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(function (results) {
                return res.redirect('/series/detail/' + req.body.series_id)
            })
            .catch (error => {
                return res.send(error)
            })
    },
```

TL;DR: If auth fails, should go back to the review url and send the data that was sent so that the user does not lose it.

So that's it, if I could use sessions/cookies I think I would be able to go back to the last route, but I can't for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post how you created your routes?

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes of course, just updated the question with some more info and the routes :)